# Magento shopping - existing cart items removed when new product added

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, addtocart, basket

Hopefully someone can help as we can't find anyone else having the same issue that we are. We have just gone live with our new Magento 2 website. We noticed that if we add an item to the cart and click on another product then add that to the cart instead of the shopping cart showing 2 products, the initial product disappears and is swapped for the new one.

more than one product can be added when you are clicking the add to cart button from the category page, the action of loading up the product page then adding it that way is what sets it off. This is how most people shop so ideally our customers should be able to add more than one product to their basket.

what makes things even weirder is we don't have this issue on our staging site, which is exactly the same as the live one as we created a new staging as a test in case there were any differences.

We removed new relic reporting which was on the server as we thought possibly this was the case and it seemed to work. More than one product could be added and we thought that was it sorted but today we noticed it is doing the same thing again.

Our site is [www.visionmarine.co.uk](http://www.visionmarine.co.uk) if you want to have a try/look. Any help would be appreciated as I've said we can't find anyone who this has happened to before and we are totally out of ideas as to what it could be.

we are running magento 2.4.3-p1

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the website, and noticed that:
ANYTIME I go to a product page, I get a new session ID.
So, basically, the user is starting a new session, this is why previous cart items are gone.
Also, I see 2 private_content_version cookies being received in the response.
Also, when I check the domains for the cookies, they are wrong
[image]

Check in your staging environment, if the domains are correct, or it is the same issue as in prod. Maybe you have some marketing analytics or pixels scripts in your prod, which cause this issue.

If you on commerce-cloud pro plan (I am not aware about other plans, or if you have self-hosting), you can use xdebug in production, to try to find the possible issue. It will not affect your live website.